# Random stars in Phaser3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a group of stars. It gives me only 1 star at the beginning. I want to make it, if I take this star, it gives me 2 stars, if I take 2 stars, it gives me 3, and so on. How can I do it?

```
stars = this.physics.add.group({
    key: 'star',
    repeat: -1,
    setXY: {
      x: Phaser.Math.RND.between(0, 900),
      y: Phaser.Math.RND.between(0, 600),
      frameQuantity: 2,
      repeat: 5
     }    
});

 this.physics.add.overlap(player, stars, collectStar, null, this);


function collectStar (player,star){
  star.disableBody(true, true);
  score += 2;    // COUNT BY 2
  scoreText.setText('Score: ' + score);
}
```

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear to me. Could you rephrase it differently? Also, can you setup the exact code you're running on a reproducible scenario, e.g. a codesandbox repo?

Comment: https://replit.com/@Peter119/stars#script.js

Comment: here is game . When boy touch star , star is gone , game should add 2 stars, when boy touch 2 stars , game should add 3 stars and so on ...

Comment: in replit page hit green btn RUN